# How to place Google maps street view panorama in tunnel with bridge

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to tell google maps street view you want to be above/under another road?  I have a path that takes someone around a cloverleaf and back out the other way, but when I set the location on the bridge it always sets them to on top of the bridge.

[image]

current code

```
  lineClickEventHandler(latLng: google.maps.LatLng) {
    this.panoramaMap.setPosition(latLng)
    this.drivingData.heading = Math.round(this.routeService.getCurrentHeading(latLng, this.polyLine))
    this.panoramaMap.setPov({
      heading: this.drivingData.heading,
      pitch: 0
    })
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (in particular a set of coordinates that demonstrates your issue)..

Comment: `42.057844, -88.028065`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there is no way to *select* a level for a set of coordinates.

If you are following a Street View "path" on the below level and don't want the API to "move" you to the top road, you could use the returned links of the current panorama you are on.

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanoramaData) each panorama has links to adjacent panoramas in the form of a collection of [`StreetViewLink`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewLink) objects.

The `getLinks()` method of the `StreetViewPanorama` class will return the same collection.

For example:

```
0: {description: "", heading: 97.73429107666016, pano: "zVIPHTGA5Pu4os139DS5sw"}
1: {description: "", heading: 277.2002563476562, pano: "wSLR0N4qAw-_Ib2Q69HvTw"}
```

If you know your heading (more or less) or say, the direction you are currently intending to move, you could compare it with the heading contained in the links and load the corresponding adjacent pano by its id.

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit**:

I did a small proof of concept to see if I could follow that road automatically based on a base heading and the provided `StreetViewLink` objects but unfortunately **that seems buggy**...

For some reason — **and although Street View imagery is available** to continue "straight ahead" on the same road — the *adjacent* links somehow start referencing the top road *at some point*. I don't know why this happens.

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/hLogwox7/). Watch your javascript console and the map while it moves along the road.

It would be interesting to test that in other places and figure out if this is a local issue or if it happens in other places as well... My guess is that it will happen in other places too.

Comment: Not a "great" solution, but looks to be the best we can do with what we have